# Bookend shareProviders not showing in last page with Desktop Display

Tags: amp-html

Recently I just started learning `amp`, I was requested to add some social media share button like facebook, Instagram & email. I followed the documentation from https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/visual_story/create_bookend/ and found when using desktop display, the buttons don't list out.

I expect the sharing button also listed in the last page of the story but so far tested only mobile display or mobile simulation could work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On desktop, AMP stories have the "share" icon at the upper right corner where it displays the `shareProviders` however, it doesn't display them on the bookend. **The sharing icons are only displayed on the bookend for mobile .**

[image: Sharing icon on desktop]

I guess it is a feature because it behaves the [same way for the CNN AMP stories.](https://www.cnn.com/ampstories/travel/americas-most-popular-national-parks)